# Not able to create new user in firebase using kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

i am new to android studio and followed a tutorial to create a sign up and login in page, i have followed the exact code, but when i want to create a new user using sign up button, nothing is happening and the firebase isnt creating any new user. If i manually create an user on firebase website i am able to login using those details, i have enabled email and password and have typed greater than 6 characters for my password, i have also searched web for various answers but havent been able to solve it, it would be great if someone could help me out. Thank you

Here is my kotlin code for signup activity

```
package com.example.signinlogin

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.signinlogin.databinding.ActivitySignupBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class signupactivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignupBinding
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySignupBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        binding.signInOption.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val email =  binding.emailId.text.toString()
        val passwordsignup = binding.passwordId.text.toString()
        val renterpassword = binding.retypepasswordId.text.toString()

        binding.submitButton.setOnClickListener {
            if(email.isNotEmpty() && passwordsignup.isNotEmpty() && renterpassword.isNotEmpty()){
                    if(passwordsignup ==  renterpassword){
                        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,passwordsignup).addOnCompleteListener {
                            if(it.isComplete)
                            {
                                val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
                                startActivity(intent)
                                finish()
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText( this,it.exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }

                        }

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText( this, "No fields should be left empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

        }

    }
}type here
```

Here is my code for build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.signinlogin'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.signinlogin"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Here is actvivity image,

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Aside from that, since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Comment: there are no errors as say in the logcat or in the code, but when i am pressing the signup after entering my details its neither moving back to mainacvitivity as i intend or creating a new user when i checked on firebase console in chrome, it simply stays in the same activity without any change

Comment: thank u will check out the resource and repo

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. It's more likely that someone here can help if you debug yourself and tell is the results of that. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Answer (score 0):

Based on their [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth), replace

```
if(it.isComplete)
```

with

```
if (task.isSuccessful) {
```

Comment: an error as unresoloved reference task in coming up

Comment: i did and still not able to add new users using sign uo